# City search in iOS

Tags: ios, search, geo

Is there any native city name search feature in iOS SDK?

For example, in lafourchette application - https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/lafourchette-reservation-restaurants/id424850908?mt=8

How in this application done search feature?

(you can see it at attached gif [Example of city name search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8DJc.gif))

It is use native Apple SDK for retrieving cities or some outside internet service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both the iOS Maps SDK or a third-party service such as Google Maps SDK or even Foursquare API. I'm not sure which one lafourchette uses but here are some useful links to get you started:

iOS Maps SDK (CLGeocoder or MKReverseGeocoder)
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH4-SW2

Google Maps SDK

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

Foursquare API

https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/libraries

Comment: As I can see, CLGeocoder gives only one suggestion. It is possible to retrieve full set of suggestions? P.S. I already see GeocoderDemo, but it always give one place mark, not a set of placemarks.

Comment: I'm no expert in CLGeocoder, but to my knowledge I don't think it has the ability to pull places nearby unless you explicitly state it's coordinates. I think you would be better off using Google or Foursquare if you want to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

The concept you are talking about is called Reverse Geocoding, and can be found in the [iOS docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html). There are also several third party companies like Google who do this as well.

Comment: "city name search" is not a reverse geocoding, it's just a _city name search_